# Volume Slider only controls Headphones item in alsa mixer

Tags: alsamixer

When I use the gnome volume slider, it does not increase or decrease the sound level, instead, while the slider moves, sound just remains constant.

So I checked alsamixer and found that the slider only controls the headphones preset and not the speaker preset. When I increase or decrease the speaker or the master preset, the level of loudness changes.

Is there a way I can make the volume slider use the speaker preset or the master preset?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, it was in the system settings.